# Example code for "google-search" gem not working?

Tags: ruby, search, rubygems

Every time I run this code (which was given as an example for the "google-search" gem), all three of my rank_for queries are returned as "Not found."

Thinking maybe the problem is in `if item = find_item(/vision\-media\.ca/, query)` as I'm not sure why they're referring to the vision-media.ca site.

Please help!  I've literally just read a book on Ruby over the weekend.

```
require "rubygems"
require "google-search"

def find_item uri, query
    search = Google::Search::Web.new do |search|
        search.query = query
        search.size = :large
        search.each_response { print "." ; $stdout.flush }
    end
        search.find { |item| item.uri =~ uri }
end

def rank_for query
    print "%35s " % query
    if item = find_item(/vision\-media\.ca/, query)
        puts " #%d" % (item.index +1)
    else
        puts " Not found"
    end
end

rank_for "hackerspace new york"
rank_for "makerspace new york"
rank_for "fab lab new york"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the example is not super obvious, because it makes use of "advanced" ruby functionality.

for example:

`search.each_response { print "." ; $stdout.flush }` registers a block of code in `{...}` that is called when another result page from google is fetched.

`search.find { |item| item.uri =~ uri }` is pretty basic concept known as an iterator, but that is probably the case where you get the "Not Found" message. it checks if the returned google uri matches the regular expression provided in `rank_for` (`/vision\-media\.ca/`). you should definitively read about regular expressions if this is new to it. they are used extensively in ruby as well.
keep in mind that the last evaluated thing in a method will be the return value of that method. so `find_item` will return the value that `find` computes (all items where uri matches vision-media.ca).

another thing is the output formatting `print "%35s " % query`. this prints out the contents of query in a specific format that is described in sprintf. learn it, love it.

that's all in terms of explaining the concepts.

a very simple implementation would be this:

```
require "google-search"

[
  "hackerspace new york",
  "makerspace new york",
  "fab lab new york"
].each do |query|
  puts "searching for #{query}"
  Google::Search::Web.new do |search|
    search.query = query
    search.size = :large
  end.each { |item| puts item.title }
end
```

Comment: Wow.  Thank you phoet, that was incredibly helpful!